# Os class finding a certain category

Tags: php, function, osclass

In osclass I need to check if my category is a job category and  add some code to it. How can i find if it is a particular category or not. Pls can any tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Helpers for categories are in `/oc-includes/osclass/helpers/hCategories.php`.

In the `while(osc_has_categories()):` loop, you can use :

- `osc_category_id()`, to check if the id is the one you're looking for.
- `osc_category_slug()`, to check if the slug is equal to job.

See http://doc.osclass.org/HCategories.php for the full list of categories helpers.